# Getting source map error warning in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

so I just recently started to get the following warning in my console:

"Source map error: request failed with status 404"
resource URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js
map resource URL: shvl.es.js.map"

Anyone ever experienced this before? I don't know what this could be?

My webpack file:

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: How do you run your app. are you using any module bundler ( webpack , parcel etc ).

Comment: yeah I'm using laravel's webpax mix

Comment: Share your webpack configuration.

Comment: I added my webpack.mix.js file

Comment: I have added an answer. go through it.

Answer (score 5):

Enable/Disable source maps can be handle by providing config `mix.sourceMaps(!mix.inProduction())`.

Make sure in development mode is enabled.

Updated mix configuration file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .sourceMaps(!mix.inProduction())
```

Comment: I updated my mix file but I'm still getting the warning

Comment: Did you check this value  `mix.inProduction` or instead run with `true` in dev mode.

Comment: I tried with .sourceMaps(!mix.inProduction) and .sourceMaps(mix.inProduction)

Comment: `mix.inProduction` is a function not a variable. Use `mix.inProduction()`

Comment: I'm still getting the warning

Comment: I fixed the warning appending .sourceMaps();